# Cannot create document in Firestore when using Sign in with Apple

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, swiftui, apple-sign-in

In my project I'm using a trigger to create a user document in Firestore when the user signs in. And this is great - everything works perfect for Google Sign-In and Facebook Login.

Here is this trigger:

```js
    exports.createAccountDocument = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async user => {
      const { uid, displayName } = user
      const username = displayName;
      const email = user.email || user.providerData[0].email;
      const profileImageUrl = uid;
      const status = "active";
    
    const str = username;
    const qwery = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        qwery[i] = str.substring(0, i + 1).replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
    }
      const keywords = qwery;
    
    
      const bio = "";
    
      return await admin
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .set({ bio, email, keywords, profileImageUrl, status, uid, username })
    })
```

For example - this is Facebook Login method:

```swift
    import SwiftUI
    import FBSDKLoginKit
    import Firebase
    
    struct FacebookAuthView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
        @Binding var showAnimation: Bool
        @Binding var showSheet: Bool
        
        init(showAnimation: Binding<Bool>, showSheet: Binding<Bool>) {
            self._showAnimation = showAnimation
            self._showSheet = showSheet
        }
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> FacebookAuthView.Coordinator {
            return FacebookAuthView.Coordinator(showAnimation: self.$showAnimation, showSheet: self.$showSheet)
        }
        
        class Coordinator: NSObject, LoginButtonDelegate {
            
            @Binding var showAnimation: Bool
            @Binding var showSheet: Bool
            
            init(showAnimation: Binding<Bool>, showSheet: Binding<Bool>) {
                self._showAnimation = showAnimation
                self._showSheet = showSheet
            }
            
            func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton, didCompleteWith result: LoginManagerLoginResult?, error: Error?) {
                if let error = error {
                  print(error.localizedDescription)
                  return
                }
                guard let token = AccessToken.current else {
                    return
                }
                
                self.showAnimation = true
                self.showSheet = false
                
                let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: token.tokenString)
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                    if let error = error, (error as NSError).code == AuthErrorCode.credentialAlreadyInUse.rawValue {
                        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { result, error in
                            // continue
                            print("signIn result: " + authResult!.user.email!)
                            if let token = firebaseRegistrationPushToken {
                                checkUserAuthSettings(pushToken: token)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // continue
                        print("Facebook Sign In")
                        if let token = firebaseRegistrationPushToken {
                            checkUserAuthSettings(pushToken: token)
                        }
                    }
    
                }
                
            }
            
            func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBLoginButton) {
                try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            }
        }
        
        func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FacebookAuthView>) -> FBLoginButton {
            let view = FBLoginButton()
            view.permissions = ["email"]
            view.delegate = context.coordinator
            return view
        }
        
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: FBLoginButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<FacebookAuthView>) { }
    }
```

But when I try to create a document when user logs in using Swign in with Apple, this doesn't work. In the Firebase console under Firebase Authentication I can see new the user, but in Firestore, no document shows up at all.

Here is my Sign in with Apple method:

```swift
    import Foundation
    import SwiftUI
    import AuthenticationServices
    import CryptoKit
    import Firebase
    
    struct AppleAuthView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
        @Binding var showAnimation: Bool
        @Binding var showSheet: Bool
        
        init(showAnimation: Binding<Bool>, showSheet: Binding<Bool>) {
            self._showAnimation = showAnimation
            self._showSheet = showSheet
        }
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> AppleAuthView.Coordinator {
            return AppleAuthView.Coordinator(showAnimation: self.$showAnimation, showSheet: self.$showSheet)
        }
        
        class Coordinator: NSObject, ASAuthorizationControllerPresentationContextProviding, ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
            
            @Binding var showAnimation: Bool
            @Binding var showSheet: Bool
            fileprivate var currentNonce: String?
            
            init(showAnimation: Binding<Bool>, showSheet: Binding<Bool>) {
                self._showAnimation = showAnimation
                self._showSheet = showSheet
                super.init()
            }
            
            func presentationAnchor(for controller: ASAuthorizationController) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
                let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
                return (viewController?.view.window!)!
            }
            
            func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
                if let appleIDCredential = authorization.credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential {
                    guard let nonce = currentNonce else {
                        fatalError("Invalid state: A login callback was received, but no login request was sent.")
                    }
                    guard let appleIDToken = appleIDCredential.identityToken else {
                        print("Unable to fetch identity token")
                        return
                    }
                    guard let idTokenString = String(data: appleIDToken, encoding: .utf8) else {
                        print("Unable to serialize token string from data: \(appleIDToken.debugDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    let credential = OAuthProvider.credential(withProviderID: "apple.com", idToken: idTokenString, rawNonce: nonce)
                    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        }
                        print("Apple Sign In")
                        if let token = firebaseRegistrationPushToken {
                            checkUserAuthSettings(pushToken: token)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error) {
                print("Sign in with Apple errored: \(error)")
            }
            
            @objc func startSignInWithAppleFlow() {
                let nonce = randomNonceString()
                currentNonce = nonce
                let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
                let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
                request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
                request.nonce = sha256(nonce)
                let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
                authorizationController.delegate = self
                authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
                authorizationController.performRequests()
            }
        
            private func randomNonceString(length: Int = 32) -> String {
                precondition(length > 0)
                let charset: Array<Character> = Array("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-._")
                var result = ""
                var remainingLength = length
                while remainingLength > 0 {
                    let randoms: [UInt8] = (0 ..< 16).map { _ in
                        var random: UInt8 = 0
                        let errorCode = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 1, &random)
                        if errorCode != errSecSuccess {
                            fatalError("Unable to generate nonce. SecRandomCopyBytes failed with OSStatus \(errorCode)")
                        }
                        return random
                    }
                    randoms.forEach { random in
                        if remainingLength == 0 {
                            return
                        }
                        if random < charset.count {
                            result.append(charset[Int(random)])
                            remainingLength -= 1
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result
            }
            
            @available(iOS 13, *)
            private func sha256(_ input: String) -> String {
                let inputData = Data(input.utf8)
                let hashedData = SHA256.hash(data: inputData)
                let hashString = hashedData.compactMap {
                    return String(format: "%02x", $0)
                }.joined()
                return hashString
            }
            
        }
        
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
            let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)
            button.addTarget(context.coordinator,action: #selector(Coordinator.startSignInWithAppleFlow),for: .touchUpInside)
            return button
        }
    
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: Context) {
        }
        
    }
```

I don't understand why the document cannot be created. In the console I can see `nil`.

Please help to fix this issue.

Updated.
Code below - is a simple function to creating user document in firestore in my app

```
    func signup(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, completed: @escaping(_ user: User) -> Void,  onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
        if !username.isEmpty && !email.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty && !imageData.isEmpty {
           AuthService.signupUser(username: username, email: email, password: password, imageData: imageData, onSuccess: completed, onError: onError)
        } else {
            
            if username == "" {
                errorString = "Please enter your name"
                onError(errorString)
//                showAlert = true
            }
            
            if email == "" {
                errorString = "Please enter yor valid email"
                onError(errorString)
//                showAlert = true
            }
            if password == "" {
                errorString = "Please create password"
                onError(errorString)
//                showAlert = true
            }
            if  image == Image(IMAGE_USER_PLACEHOLDER) {
                errorString = "Please upload your avatar"
                onError(errorString)
//                showAlert = true
            }
        }
    }
```

and here is AuthService.signupUser method

```
static func signupUser(username: String, email: String, password: String, imageData: Data, onSuccess: @escaping(_ user: User) -> Void, onError: @escaping(_ errorMessage: String) -> Void) {
        //Firebase.createAccount(username: username, email: email, password: password, imageData: imageData)
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authData, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                onError(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            guard let userId = authData?.user.uid else { return }
            
            
            let storageAvatarUserId = Ref.STORAGE_AVATAR_USERID(userId: userId)
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
            
            StorageService.saveAvatar(userId: userId, username: username, email: email, imageData: imageData, metadata: metadata, storageAvatarRef: storageAvatarUserId, onSuccess: onSuccess, onError: onError)
            
        }
    }
```

I know that apple sign in cannot take users image & it's ok - my cloud trigger fill this field in document users uid & in my app if user avatar = nil - it's takes universal clipart, It's ok, newer mind.
And this is User file

```
import Foundation

struct User: Encodable, Decodable {
    var uid: String
    var email: String
    var profileImageUrl: String
    var username: String
    var bio: String
    var keywords: [String]
    var status: String?
}
```

my security rules in firebase are simple, here they are

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call `createAccountDocument`?

Comment: hanks for responding, @Peter Friese the fact is that I realized that Firebase Authentication does not automatically add user data to Firestore. If i want to have a document for each user in Firestore, i'll have to create that yourself. - Frank van Puffelen told.
So i make trigger function that I have attached in this question. This automatically creates a user's document in the firestore when he logs into the system using social networks. This method automatically works fine in cases with google and facebook but not apple sign, I can see the user in authorization, but no document is created

Comment: Got it. To understand what's causing the issue, can you please add the code for creating the user document to your original question, as well as your security rules. Did you enable Sign in with Apple in the Firebase console in the Authentication section?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding @PeterFriese
i have added simple function to creating user document in firestore in my app (by manual signIn), also AuthService.signupUser method, User structure file and firebase rules. Yes i enable Sign in with Apple in the Firebase console in the Authentication section. As i say before - i can see users who sign in with apple in this section, but the document for the user is not created in this case. But a document is created when entering through Google or fb (using a trigger) or standard registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is - that Apple don’t get username.
Issue is solved.